# Is there a different copy of $\Bbb{R}$ in $\Bbb{C}$ such that the extension is algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Since $\Bbb{C}$ contains a non-trivial copy of itself, I know that there are multiple subfields of $\Bbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$. But these inclusions make the extension non-algebraic. So are there other ways of including $\Bbb{R}$ in $\Bbb{C}$ (as a field) keeping the extension algebraic? Or is it that, given $\Bbb{C}$, there is an algebraic way to define the usual copy of $\Bbb{R}$?

I can see that this is equivalent to asking for an order 2 automorphism of $\Bbb{C}$ which is not the usual conjugation. But I could neither come up with one, nor prove it does not exist.

More generally, if $\overline F$ is finite over $F$, is the inclusion unique?

Comment: What non-trivial copy of $\mathbb C$ does $\mathbb C$ contain? I've never heard such statement before, I'm interested.

Comment: This is all highly dependent of what your definition of embedding is. Do you just mean subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as rings?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva As rings $\overline{\mathbb{C}(X)}\cong\mathbb{C}$. So the embedding of rings $\mathbb{C}\to\overline{\mathbb{C}(X)}$ produces such an example.

Comment: @Patrick: Consider the algebraic closure of $\Bbb C(t)$. It is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$ itself.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes. Nothing to do with the topology, if that is what you were asking. I will edit the question appropriately.

Comment: @ronno Take other automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ of order $2$ besides conjugation. Their fixed points will work. I believe there are others, before you ask, but it's late, so I won't make any promises.

Comment: @Asaf : I thought we were looking for an embedding $F \to \mathbb C$, not $\mathbb C \to F$! And I don't really understand how this embedding could be surjective since mapping $1$ to the $1 \in \overline{\mathbb C(X)}$ implies everything has nothing to do with $X$ in the image... you guys are confusing me. O.o

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva $\Bbb{C} \subsetneq \Bbb{C}(X) \to \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva It's not an embedding of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, just of rings.

Comment: @Patrick: To go outside of my comfort zone, you're working in the wrong category. :-)

Comment: Let $B$ be a transcendence basis of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$, any non-identity bijective $\psi \colon B \to B$ of order 2 induces an automorphism $\Psi \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ of order 2.

Comment: @AlexYoucis : Can we discuss this somewhere? I don't think I can answer the question but I'm interested to understand this embedding.

Comment: @martini Do you mind posting that as an answer? Maybe with a bit of details fleshed out for future visitors?

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question about embeddings of the real numbers such that the extension of the complex numbers are algebraic over the image is different from the question of order 2 automorphisms.

1. All maps $\tau:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ turning $\Bbb{C}/\Bbb{R}$ into an algebraic extension agree up to the action of $Aut(\Bbb{C})$.

The first is a question about Galois theory. Let $\tau:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ be such a map. Then it extends to an automorphism of $\Bbb{C} = \tau(\Bbb{R})(i)$. Let us call this $\gamma$. Then the complex conjugation associated to $\tau$ is just the $\gamma$-conjugate of the usual one.

Now comes the confusing part.

2. There are index two subfields of $\Bbb{C}$ not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$, but they are all real closed.

**Theorem(Artin-Schreier):** Let F be a field whose algebraic closure is a finite extension. Then F is either algebraically closed or real closed.

However, while real closed fields share many properties of the reals, they are not necessarily isomorphic even when they have the same cardinality. Note that the hyperreal numbers are real closed of continuum cardinality, but they are not isomorphic as abstract field to the real numbers, since such an isomorphism would respect the order(positive elements are precisely the squares). However, the algebraic closure of the hyperreals is a quadratic extension and by cardinality reasons isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$. Taking the complex conjugation yields a nonconjugate involution of $\Bbb{C}$.

3. Involutions need not extend to involutions on the algebraic closure.

By the way there is no guarantee that an involution extends to an involution on the algebraic closure. Just take $\Bbb{Q}(i)(t_1,t_2)$ and the involution exchanging the $t_i$. Then an extension to an involution of $\Bbb{C}$ would contradict the Artin-Schreier theorem.

Comment: I think it should be made clearer in your answer that you are basically saying (and explaining why): "there are non-trivial involutions of $\mathbb{C}$ whose fixed field is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$". It took me two readings to see where you were going with your argumentation.

Comment: I think you are completely right. I changed the answer to follow your suggestion.