# Subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Is there any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ but not $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51085/subfields-of-mathbbc-isomorphic-to-mathbbr-that-have-baire-property-w

Answer (score 7):

Let $B$ be a trascendence basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$, so that $\mathbb R$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q(B)$. The set $B$ is infinite: let $B'$ be the result of removing one element. Since $B$ and $B'$ are in bijection, there is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q(B')$ contained in $\mathbb C$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and it is not $\mathbb R$ because it does not contain the element we removed.

Comment: From here can we say the possible number of ring homomorphisms from R to C?

Comment: There are a lot of them, by taking subsets of my $B$ and repeating thte construction you get many many others.

Comment: Why there is an algebraic extension isomorphic to R and is that a field isomorphism or just a Q-vector space isomorphism?